# Synaptic installed programmes

Tags: synaptic

When listing "Installed" GIMP with Synaptic it shows 2.8.2-0.1, this is even after running Reload, however I recently updated to 2.10.6 also I cannot find a listing of 2.10.6 as being installed. I'd appreciate any comments on this apparent "out of date" listing. I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 MATE on an ASUS X550 laptop.

Hal_v

Comment: How, exactly, did you update to 2.10.6 if not through Synaptic?

Comment: I updated through the terminal, as GIMP wasn't showing up as an update in Synaptic. Hal_v

Comment: How, exactly? `sudo apt-get install gimp` or what? I suspect that you installed a version outside of the official Ubuntu repositories, yes?

Comment: I loaded directly from the developer's PPA  Otto Kesselgulasch's  PPA, after uninstalling the earlier version.

Comment: Sorry chilli555 I should have mentioned it was my first attempt at a flatpak.

Comment: Thank you for that "user535733" that certainly explains it, your advice is much appreciated. I think I'll call this solved, thank you both.

Comment: @user535733 I suggest that you make this into an answer that hal_v can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synaptic is aware only of deb packages. Synaptic does not maintain it's own package database - it uses the same apt and dpkg database used by apt, aptitude, dpkg, and other deb-based managers. If you install a deb package using any of these tools, you can uninstall it using any other of these tools.

Synaptic (nor any other apt-based application) cannot detect flatpacks, snaps, pips, wheels, compiled, or any other type of package or method of installing...since those are not deb packages.

Ubuntu does not have any single application that can see all the possible methods of installing software. In this open-source environment, somebody can add a whole new method tomorrow without checking with any gatekeeper. It's up to you, the user, to keep track of the methods you use to install and to use the appropriate tool for that method.

Comment: Thank you user535733 for you answer that explains the difference I was noticing. I assume in spite of having seemingly removing GIMP 2.8 prior to updating to 2.10, there appears to be some remnants left. Do you feel it would be safe to mark these for "Complete removal" in Synaptic. I can appreciate you may not feel like making that decision for me, but your comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends upon the remnants. Remnants in your /home directory will **never** be removed by apt. Remnants in the /etc directory need --purge (complete removal).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I should have realised that, but my knowledge is just above rudimentary and I frequently need reminding of the basics. Also sorry for the delay in replying.